# How do I plus these values in a list

Tags: list-manipulation

Hi I need to plus 3 values together each time for the rest of the list. How do I basically add the 3 sets of values together each time. When I try Plus[] it returns the same input values back to me without adding them together within the brackets {}. The values represent 22 points in 3 dimensions. Any help greatly appreciated. I'm still finding my way!

[{{148.`, -76.1`, 73.8`}, {134.`, -69.6`, 88.8`}, {155.`, -70.6`, 
   80.2`}, {134.`, -65.5`, 92.6`}, {142.`, -65.4`, 
   94.2`}, {169.`, -66.8`, 89.5`}, {158.`, -71.6`, 
   92.8`}, {155.`, -73.7`, 97.2`}, {160.`, -65.5`, 
   104.`}, {132.`, -62.`, 99.9`}, {118.`, -68.1`, 
   85.9`}, {133.`, -58.2`, 108.`}, {147.`, -54.7`, 
   113.`}, {149.`, -55.7`, 117.`}, {140.`, -55.7`, 
   113.`}, {159.`, -44.6`, 124.`}, {156.`, -59.6`, 
   111.`}, {154.`, -57.`, 112.`}, {168.`, -75.8`, 
   96.4`}, {170.`, -71.7`, 103.`}, {167.`, -70.8`, 
   114.`}, {161.`, -68.1`, 114.`}}]

Comment: Try `Plus @@@ {{148., -76.1, 73.8}, {134., -69.6, 88.8}, {155., -70.6, 80.2}}`.

Comment: `Total /@{{148., -76.1, 73.8}, {134., -69.6, 88.8}, {155., -70.6, 80.2}}` is another way